# Powershell Get-ChildItem, filtered on date with Owner and export to txt or csv

Tags: powershell, csv, get-childitem

I am trying to export a list of documents modified files after a set date, including its owners from a recursive scan using `Get-ChildItem`.

For some reason I cannot get it to port out to a file/csv:

```
$Location2 = "\\fs01\DATAIT"
$loc2 ="melb"

cd $Location2

Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.lastwritetime -gt [datetime]"2017/05/01" } | foreach { Write-Host $_.Name "," $_.lastwritetime "," ((get-ACL).owner) } > c:\output\filelisting-$loc2.txt
```

Could any of the PowerShell gurus on here shed some light please?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are using `Write-Host` which explicitly sends output to the console (which you then can't redirect elsewhere). The quick fix is as follows:

```
 Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object {  $_.lastwritetime -gt [datetime]"2017/05/01" } | foreach { "$($_.Name),$($_.lastwritetime),$((get-ACL).owner)" } > filelisting-$loc2.txt
```

This outputs a string to the standard output (the equivalent of using `Write-Output`). I've made it a single string which includes the variables that you wanted to access by using the subexpression operator `$()` within a double quoted string. This operator is necessary to access the properties of objects or execute other cmdlets/complex code (basically anything more than a simple $variable) within such a string.

You could improve the code further by creating an object result, which would then allow you to leverage other cmdlets in the pipeline like `Export-CSV`. I suggest this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object {  $_.lastwritetime -gt [datetime]"2017/05/01" } | ForEach-Object { 
    $Properties = [Ordered]@{
        Name  = $_.Name
        LastWriteTime = $_.LastWriteTime
        Owner = (Get-ACL).Owner
    }

    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties
} | Export-CSV $Loc2.csv
```

This creates a hashtable `@{}` of the properties you wanted and then uses that hashtable to create a PowerShell Object with `New-Object`. This Object is then returned to standard output, which goes into the pipeline so when the ForEach-Object loop concludes all the objects are sent in to `Export-CSV` which then outputs them correctly as a CSV (as it takes object input).

---

- As an aside, here is an interesting read from the creator of PowerShell on why [Write-Host is considered harmful](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/).
- `[Ordered]` requires PowerShell 3 or above. If you're using PowerShell 2, remove it. It just keeps the order of the properties within the object in the order they were defined.

Comment: Perfect!  thanks a lot for your answer, worked a treat!
I have started using the export-CSV for other scripts and its great, i had no idea it existed haha.  Cheers.